The upper bound of $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$
As the title mentioned, I want to calculte
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}.
\end{equation}
Note that if $m=n$, the result is simply 1. However, when $m<n$, this seems to become a open problem of the tail of beta distribution. Therefore, I only expect to obtain an upper bound w.r.t. $x$. By the way, in my exact problem, $m\approx \frac n3$. Asymptotic is also welcomed, but strict upper bound is favourable.

Here is an approximation approach.
Instead of refering to a beta distribution, consider a binomial $Bin(n,p)$ random variable $X$. In this framework :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
can be interpreted as $P(X \le m)$.
Now work with the normal approximation $N(np,\sqrt{np(1-p)})$ of a $Bin(n,p)$.

Thank you for your reply. This can generate a fine asymptotic. Is there any way to obtain a strict upper bound with normal approximation (can we analyze the remainer terms)?

Maybe by using a Gram-Charlier/Edgeworth series but I am not sure...

For a better approximation, think to "continuity correction" as described here
